# I installed flutter on ubuntu without Android studio and it has been working then all of a sudden its throwing me an error,why?

Tags: flutter

francis@homelaptop:~/project/flybird$ flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                             45.2s
Resolving dependencies...

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "/home/francis/project/flybird/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/francis/project/flybird/android/build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  >   java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/francis/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/default/dosdevices/z:/media/francis/Interesante/.Trash-1000/files:
  >   Input/output error
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 10s
  Command: /home/francis/project/flybird/android/gradlew app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your gradle version from project => android => build. For me :

   `dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
   }`
2. Use latest sdk tool version 28 not 29
3. Open terminal from Tools >>Flutter and run these following commands

   flutter upgrade

   flutter doctor

Comment: if problem persists install android studio

Comment: thanks alot,i just resorted to installing android studio and it worked.